# Why this cocycle $\mathrm{char} (h)$ is not a coboundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Maybe this is a stupid question and I'm missing something very trivial. Let $X$ be a smooth manifold, $$h \colon Z_{k-1} (X, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$$ an abelian group morphism such that $$h (\partial c) = \left(\int_c \omega_h\right) \mod \mathbb{Z}$$ for some fixed $\omega_h \in \Omega^k (X)$ and $$\tilde{h} \colon Z_{k-1} (X, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ a lifting of $h$ through the canonical projection $\mathbb{R} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

By definition, there exists $$n \colon B_{k-1}(X, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ such that $\tilde{h} (\partial c) = \int_c \omega_h + n (\partial c)$.

Let $$\mu^{\tilde{h}} \colon C_k (X, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ be defined by $$\mu^{\tilde{h}} (c)= (\int_c \omega_h) - \tilde{h} (\partial c).$$ Then $\mu^{\tilde{h}}(c) = -n (\partial c)$. Let $$\tilde{n} \colon C_{k-1} (X, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ be the unique extension by zero of $n$ defined by noting that $B_{k-1} (X, \mathbb{Z})$ have a complement in $C_{k-1} (X, \mathbb{Z})$ (because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID) and sending this complement to zero. Then $\mu^{\tilde{h}} = \delta \tilde{n}$ and, therefore, $[\mu^{\tilde{h}}] = 0 \in H^k (X, \mathbb{Z})$.

However it's known that $\mathrm{char}(h) = [\mu^{\tilde{h}}] $ can be non-zero and, in fact, it defines the Chern class when $k = 2$ (see, for instance, page 22 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.6457v2.pdf ).

**What's wrong in my argument???**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $n(\partial c)$ is not well defined, two chains $c,c'$ may have the same boundary, so $n$ depends of $c$ not of $\partial c$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following your claim. $\tilde{h}$ is any lifting of $h$, so it's well defined. Furthermore $h (\partial c) = \int_c \omega_h \mod \mathbb{Z}$ by definition, i.e, $h|_{B_{k-1}} = \omega_h$ (under the de Rham isomorphism $Hom (H_k (X, \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{R}) = H^{k} (X, \mathbb{R}) \cong H^k_{dR} (X)$).

Comment: But $n$ is not well defined,  $\partial c=\partial c'$ does not imply $\int_c\omega =\int_{c'}\omega$ they coincide up to an integer. The first formula says $h(\partial c)=\int_c\omega_h$ mod n.

Comment: Sorry again, maybe I'm just too dumb, but I can't follow you. Since $\tilde{h}$ is a lifting of $h$, for each boundary $\partial c \in B_{k-1}$, there exists $n (\partial c) \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\tilde{h} (\partial c) = \int_c \omega_h + n (\partial c)$.

Comment: If you replace $c$ by $c'$ which have the same boundary, do you obtain the same $n(\partial c)$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course. $n$ is a function on boundaries and not on any chain.

Comment: $n(\partial c)=\int_c\omega-\tilde h(\partial c)$ so this formula depends of the choice of $c$.

Comment: Of course, thanks for your help.